# I have a list of strings that end with different extensions how would I tell Python to not print the .zip strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a list of strings that are file paths, and I want to print only the paths that do not end with .zip. I can't use glob or os since this is a list and was not found through os.chdir("/mydir"). This is what I tried and it does not work.

```
list = ['/user/adi/test.zip', '/user/adi/test.csv', /user/adi/testing.zip, /user/adi/testing.txt]
for lis in list:
    if lis not in ['.zip']:
        print lis
```

Anyway for me to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Using 'list' as a variable name is a bad choice because it will override the Python built-in datatype.

Comment: Sorry that is not my actual list name I just used that as an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
if not lis.endswith('.zip'):
   print lis
```

[`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) also could be useful depending on what you're doing.

---

As pointed out in the comments, if you're looking to filter the list, you can simply use the above expression as part of a list comprehension:

```
list_without_zip = [ x for x in list_with_zip if not x.endswith('.zip') ]
```

Comment: YaY I like you :D I send you kisses :* This all means that this works. And I will accept this in 8 minutes :)

Comment: If you want to build a list of the non-zipfiles for other uses, you can use either a list comprehension ( `nonzips = [lis for lis in list if not lis.endswith('.zip')]`) or `filter` (`nonzips = filter(lambda l: not l.endsiwth('.zip'), list)`).

Answer (score 2):

```
print filter(lambda x:not x.endswith(".zip") , my_list)
```

or if you want it to look the same ...

```
print "\n".join(filter(lambda x:not x.endswith(".zip") , my_list))
```

Comment: I would argue that `'\n'.join( x for x in mylist if not x.endswith('.zip'))` is much easier to read :)

Comment: I would probably agree in terms of readability :) (which is very impt. in python)

Comment: Readability matters in every other language that I've ever written code in ... :-)

Comment: yeah but its less important (and less achievable) in something like perl (for example)